# unable to start webapp on SCP Neo build with latest s4sdk

Tags: java, s4sdk

Java applications built using the latest(2.13.1, 2.12.0) s4SDK can not start on SCP NEO. It works fine when deploying Helloworld alone.

Please give me any suggestions,please.

App (.war) built using s4SDK 2.3.1 can be deployed and started properly.
The both are the same java code, which is based on s4sdk tutorial, to get business partner data from s/4hana.

> **following is the log**
>
> 2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##04:32:08.761 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase -
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: | 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/qmyneoproject2120-application]]|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation
>   scanner for web module qmyneoproject2120-application: null| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2305)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1188)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   ... 10 common frames
>   omitted| 2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##Caused by:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation
>   scanner for web module qmyneoproject2120-application: null| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2303)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   ... 16 common frames
>   omitted| 2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1169)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.(AnnotationFinder.java:147)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.(AnnotationFinder.java:160)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.(FinderFactory.java:546)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   ... 18 common frames
>   omitted| 2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##04:32:08.777
>   [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig -
>   Error deploying web application archive
>   [/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/qmyneoproject2120-application.war]| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/qmyneoproject2120-application]]|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)| 2019 03 29
>   04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)|
>   2019 03 29 04:32:08#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)|
>
> ---

Comment: Do you have more details or a small minimal example that shows the issue (maybe on GitHub)? It's hard to tell from the error log what the issue is. Also, can you post a dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: following is the step for reproducing :  problem happens when archetypeVersion changed form 2.3.1 to latest. https://github.com/techpmsap/S4HC_Leonardo_PW2018/blob/master/Day1/Exercise_11/Exercise_11.md  and https://github.com/techpmsap/S4HC_Leonardo_PW2018/blob/master/Day1/Exercise_15/Exercise_15.md

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: I've just tried the suggested steps with the version upgrade and I could not find an issue, the app starts normally. Could you share a minimal non-working example?

Comment: Thanks, after generate Helloworld as Ex_11 (this case I also no issue), then modefied adding 2 java class BPDetail and BPServlet as like Ex_15. then the issue happed. I also will check again using new latest s4sdk.

Comment: @YaMassa: Any updates worth sharing?

Comment: I tried using latest S4SDK. It is 2.13.3. But issue was not solved. means after uploading to Neo, aplication could not start with error (same as my first posted).

Comment: @YaMassa Can you share your project on GitHub or similar so that we can also reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Sander Wozniak , thanks.  I shared my project at  https://github.com/YaMassa/S4HCSDK_Test

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @YaMassa I can reproduce the issue, will update you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using the incorrect scope `compile` for Lombok.

It should work with scope `provided`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  After changing the dependency scope, App started correctly.